# Debug Detective: Checkout Success Periodically Gets Skipped in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, debugging

I'm having a strange problem after customers complete checkout in Magento 2.2.  About 15-20% of the time when they click "Place Order," the order is placed on the backend and they see the "You have no items in your shopping cart" page on the frontend.  However, the majority of the time it does take them to the checkout success page as it should.

[image: Shopping Cart page]

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out how it's skipping the checkout success page from time to time. I've tried to eliminate other variables by disabling plugins, payment methods, etc., but it's completely random.  Anyway, I though that if I were in Developer mode and had the debugging log enabled, I'd see some clues when it does skip the checkout success page.  No luck. The debug log is being written, but it doesn't log anything different from when the checkout success is being skipped and when it isn't.

Anyway, I need some input as to the best way to troubleshoot and debug this strange problem.  What is everyone's preferred method to debugging in Magento 2? Any online resources that would help me understand the debug process better? Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure that you application has some issue.May some custom modules are creating This error.As a suggestion, you should be remove all extension and  then enable production mode and see what happen

Comment: Are you sure that it's not happening in a specific situation only? For example when a specific payment/shipping method is selected?

Comment: I've disabled all plugins/extensions and tried so many different combinations trying to identify a trigger that was causing it. Nothing.  I was hoping for a better debug solution that would actually tell me something. Obviously when Magento passes over the checkout success page, it's because something happened and I want it to speak to me so I can fix it.